# Find Missing Row When Comparing Table

Tags: python

Is there anyway I can compare two different databases (postgresl, sql server) and return the missing rows? I am missing one row in the postgresql table that is not in the sql server one and have no clue how to return that answer to me.

I have two connections opened for postgresql (bpo_table_results) and for sql server(rps_table_results)

postgresql table:

```
date     count   amount
1/1/21    500    1,500,654.12
```

sql server table:

```
date      count   amount
1/1/21    500    1,625,654.12
1/2/21    4541   3,457,787.24
```

expected results:

```
The row in the amount of 3,457,787.24 is missing from your posgresql table.
```

code:

```
def queryRPS(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor):
    rps_item_count_l = []
    rps_icl_amt_l = []

    rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' """
    rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

    for row in rps_table_results:
        rps_item_count = row[16]
        rps_item_count_l.append(rps_item_count)
        rps_icl_amt = row[18]
        rps_icl_amt_l.append(rps_icl_amt)

def queryBPO(postgres_conn, postgres_cursor,rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l):

    bpo_results_l = []
    rps_results_l = []

    for rps_count, rps_amount in zip(rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l):
        rps_amount_f = str(rps_amount).rstrip('0')
        rps_amount_f = ("{:,}".format(float(rps_amount_f)))
        bpo_icl_awk_q_2 = """select * from ppc_data.icl_awk where num_items = '%s' and
                            file_total = '%s' """ % (str(rps_count), str(rps_amount_f))

        postgres_cursor.execute(bpo_icl_awk_q_2)
        bpo_table_results = postgres_cursor.fetchall()

        rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from rps..sendfile where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%ICL%' """
        rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l = queryRPS(sql_server_conn, sql_server_cursor)
queryBPO(postgres_conn, postgres_cursor, rps_item_count_l, rps_icl_amt_l)
```

Comment: `set(all_dates_in_one_table) - set(all_dates_in_another_table)` will give you all dates which are only in the first table. OTOH, it would be more efficient to do that on the SQL level... and to have primary keys, foreign keys and other helpful stuff

Comment: **I am missing one row in the postgresql table that *is not in* the sql server.** Do you mean: **I am missing one row in the postgresql table that *is in* the sql server.**? You need to load the sql server table in the postgresql table database and then you can do a reasonable analysis of what is missing.